# centOS current connected users on your server

Tags: linux, centos

I'm hosted on a Linux box with CentOS on it and I'm running a webserver there. I want to know how to display the live users that are viewing my website in real-time, is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

> I want to know how to display the live users that are viewing my
>   website in real-time, is it possible?

Well, yes, it is, but it depends on whether you are requiring users to authenticate so that you know which users in particular are connected. This is more of a programming issue than a OS issue or an Apache issue.

You can write a simple script, for example, to tell you how many active connections to port 80 you have but this will not be an indication of how many unique users you have, or who in particular is hitting your website, etc.

Answer (score 0):

*IF* you are writing your own web application and *IF* you require users to authenticate and *IF* you establish thresholds for how long a user is considered "active", then sure, you can add code to display a list of people currently using your website.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are trying to see the active connection list on your network.

You can do so by running `netstat -n -A inet` command.

This list may contain internal connections too including web-servers, emails, mysql and any connections that are required.

However the best approach is to do application side active users list as advised above.